# After logging into a webapp with GAS I'm unable to navigate to other pages (.aspx) on the website with GAS. How do I do this?

Tags: google-apps-script

My client has a webapp they use for scheduling appointments and tracking a lot of data on their members. First, you get a page that requires you to login with the account name. Then a second login page comes up requiring a Username and Password.

I'm using `UrlFetchAll` for these and they both appear to be working. I get `302` response codes for each and there are no errors in the full response. After the User login page I am brought to a page `appname/..../Calendar.aspx` that shows the appointments calendar for the week. Instead of the calendar page I want to navigate to the Reports page at `appname/..../ListReports.aspx`. I have tried doing this with `UrlFetchApp`. I get a `200` (successful) from `getResponse`, but when I look at the full response in the Log it shows an error which includes the text:

> There is an error determining which application you are signing into. Return to the application and try again.

The reason I am going through this is so that I can have my GAS script run at a regular time each day to download various reports, consolidate them, etc. to speed up my analyses and help automate them.

I am new to `GAS` and `JavaScript` in general. I used to do some `C++` back in the day and `VBA` here and there. I don't know if this has to do with cookies, states, sessions, redirects or what.

Comment: You're gonna need to whittle this down to a specific problem that can be fixed. Without seeing how you go from "logged in" to "go to a page I want", or how the server handles it (the server likely processes some actions when the user clicks on a link, etc), I don't think anyone can give an answer. The best approach? Contact the client about programmatic access to the underlying API that the webapp is using, rather than try to remotely drive the webapp.

Comment: @tehhowch thank you for the feedback. Unfortunately the webapp doesn't have an API to access the report data. I did look for other tools to possibly use instead of programming this as a noob. I'll spend a little more time on it and if I can come up with a more specific question, I'll follow-up here.

Comment: the webapp gets its data from somewhere. Get yours from there too